# Java read in with spaces

Tags: java, function, methods, logic, procedure

I have a simple program that involves saving to and reading from a text file/2D array. The issue is that strings stored in the 2D array may include spaces. I can't seem to find a way to read/write to a file ignoring the spaces but still including them. What changes can I make to these two functions?

Read from file:

```
    public static void getArrayData(String [][] array){


      try {
         Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(new File("arrayData.txt"));


         for(int i=0; i<array.length;  i++)
         {
            for(int j=0; j<array[i].length; j++)
            {


              if ( ! scan2.hasNext() )  
                  return; 

               array[i][j]=scan2.next(); 

            } 


         }


      } 

      catch (FileNotFoundException e)
         { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
         }    

   }
```

Write to the file:

```
   public static void Save(String [][] array){

      try {
         PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("arrayData.txt"));

         for(int x=0; x<array.length; x++){
            for(int y=0; y<array[x].length; y++){
               writer.write(String.valueOf(array[x][y] + " "));
            }
            writer.println(); 
         }

         writer.flush();  
         writer.close();        



      } 
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
         {      
         e.printStackTrace();
         }


   }
```

The more simplistic the solution the better, as I am still extremely novice.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does "*ignoring the spaces but still including them*" actually mean?

Comment: @PM77-1 I mean like when writing and reading not having them but when printing to screen having them. I'm very new to programming. My program has many more issues than just this....

Answer (score 1):

Use `nextLine` instead of `next` to read the entire line.

```
array[i][j]= scan2.nextLine();
```

Comment: What makes you think that OP's file contains end-of-line characters?

Comment: Helped but hasn't fixed my program

Comment: @userX if it helped but hasn't fixed, then I suppose it fixed the actual issue, but you have another one ? Then we need to know what it is.